# How to copy data from memory to numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy, copy

For example, I have a variable which point to a vector contains many elements in memory, I want to copy element in vector to a numpy array, what should I do except one by one copy? Thx

Comment: can you give a concrete code example?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your vector can be represented like that:-

```
import array

x = array('l', [1, 3, 10, 5, 6])   # an array using python's built-in array module
```

Casting it as a `numpy` array will then be:-

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is packed in a buffer in native float format:

```
a = numpy.fromstring(buf, dtype=float, count=N)
```